# RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and am writing a program to print 6 random numbers for a lottery ticket. I am receiving an error,

> -Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source -code - cannot find symbol
>   -  symbol:   variable numbers
>   -  location: class lotto.Lottery
>   -   at lotto.Lottery.printNumbers(Lottery.java:52)
>   -   at lotto.Lottery.main(Lottery.java:34)
>   -Java Result: 1

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lottery {

    static ArrayList<Integer> lottoNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int MAX_NUMBERS = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        generateNumbers();
        printNumbers();
    }

    private static void generateNumbers()
    {
        int ticketNumber;
        Random generateRandomNumber = new Random();

        for (int count = 0; count < MAX_NUMBERS; count++)
        {
            ticketNumber = 1 + generateRandomNumber.nextInt(59);
            lottoNumbers.add(new Integer(ticketNumber));
        }
    }

    private static void printNumbers()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for( Integer number : numbers )  
        {
           if (count < 5)
               if (count == 4)
                   System.out.print(number);
               else
                    System.out.print(number + ", ");
           else
           {
               System.out.println("\nPower Ball: " + number);
               count++;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh something so simple, so i fixed that, and it got rid of the error, but it still will not print the "Power Ball: " line. the output looks like "15, 52, 44, 54, 23, 22," when i want it to look like "55, 31, 57, 46, 20 Power Ball: 24"

Comment: if you solved ur problem..you can post your solution as an answer to ur own question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a compilation error, hence the program fails to run: the variable `numbers` is not defined anywhere. If you want to loop over the generated numbers, use `lottoNumbers` which was filled by the `generateNumbers` method. You should also increment `count++` after each element is printed (I would strongly encourage you to always use curly braces after `if` statements to avoid bugs):

```
int count = 0;
for (Integer number : lottoNumbers) {
    if (count < 5) {
        if (count == 4) {
            System.out.print(number);
        } else {
            System.out.print(number + ", ");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nPower Ball: " + number);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Ugh something so simple, so i fixed that, and it got rid of the error, but it still will not print the "Power Ball: " line. the output looks like "15, 52, 44, 54, 23, 22," when i want it to look like "55, 31, 57, 46, 20 Power Ball: 24"

Comment: @user4617245 You're not incrementing `count` when printing the elements. See my updated answer.

Comment: Nevermind i figured out that part of it, just had to remove some brackets.